# Messaging exception: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException in sftp outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

Messaging exception: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/.sftpChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

I am trying to send file from local to remote server.

My application context is below

```
 <bean id="startupBean" class="com.SchedulerImpl" init-method="run"/>
 <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>

 <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
</bean>
    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${destination.host}"/>
        <property name="privateKey" value="${destination.privateKey}"/>
        <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${destination.privateKeyPassphrase}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${destination.port}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${destination.user}"/>
        <property name="sessionConfig" ref="props"/>
    </bean>

     <util:properties id="props">
            <prop key="PreferredAuthentications">publickey</prop>
        </util:properties>  
    <int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

    <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" 
                                        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                        channel="sftpChannel" 
                                        auto-startup ="false"
                                        charset="UTF-8" 
                                        remote-directory="/destinationFolder/"
                                        remote-file-separator="/">
     </int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

     <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="contextRefreshEvents"/>

     <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="contextRefreshEvents"
                            expression="sftpOutboundAdapter.start()" />
```

so I get same instance of applicationContext inside code of sftp class as:

ApplicationContext context = appContext.getApplicationContext();

MessageChannel sftpChannel = (MessageChannel)context.getBean("sftpChannel");

and @Autowired private ApplicationContextProvider appContext;
inside same sftp class.

there's another class ApplicationContextProvider which implements ApplicationContextAware which helps me to get current ApplicaitonContext.

I dont understand why I get No subscriber found.
I have put auto-startup=false.
what would be correct way of getting current sftpChannel bean which gives me same instance of applicationContext.

If I do appContext = new classpathxmlapplicationcontext(applicationcontext.xml )
I get error in startupBean, so I dont want to do that.

Now I am implementing ApplicationContextAware, and I get Messaging exception.

could anyone please help me out?

I am using spring 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have shared a lot from your mind and in the end your question becomes in a mess.

From other side let me explain what's going on.

Since you have `auto-startup ="false"` on the `<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>`, any `send` to the `sftpChannel` will cause that Exception until you start that adapter.

From other side I see you do that, although we don't see who initiates `contextRefreshEvents` messages, but we believe you that it is `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

And one more point here that you don't show us that `file from local`. OK, I guess it is `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Which is pollable and starts to poll the local director just after application start up. So, that may cause `Dispatcher has no subscribers`, because `sftpOutboundAdapter` hasn't been started yet.

Let me know, if I went wrong way in my reasoning, but you expected something different.

**UPDATE**

To start endpoint (or any other `Lifecycle` component) programmatically you should `inject` it to your service:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sftpOutboundAdapter")
private Lifecycle sftpOutboundAdapter;

....

sftpOutboundAdapter.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, bt if I dont have  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="contextRefreshEvents"/>

     <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="contextRefreshEvents"
                            expression="sftpOutboundAdapter.start()" />  inside applicationContext,    how do I start outbound adapter from code?

Comment: Now I get error:Messaging exception: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
does that mean I need do---> @Autowired
 @Qualifier("sftpSessionFactory")
 private Lifecycle sftpSessionFactory; and sftpSessionFactory.start(); inside code?